# Particular Management Crashes in each Minute (NServiceBus)

Tags: c#, nservicebus

Particular Management on my system always fails. I disabled all other application who uses NServiceBus and still Particular Management Service fails.

[image: Error from the Crash Report]

Comment: please include your error message as text and not screenshot! so people can easier search for the same issue.

Comment: I'm from Particular Software and I don't believe we install software in a 4.0 folder. Next to that, the NServiceBus Host is a component we provide to make it easy to host your own solutions, running NServiceBus, on premise. Could you please provide a stacktrace of the error?

Comment: I just noticed you already sent us a mail directly.